# Is there a way to test if a directories contents are only there because of a mount?

Tags: bash, testing, virtualbox, mount

There are too many keywords in my question to google this :)
I have a bash scripts and wish to test if a directory is only poupulated because of a mountI did in the script. IOW, the following events have occured:

1)The directory was created with the -p argument eg: `mkdir -p myDir`

2)It has been established that the system use VirtualBox:

```
if [ -f /sbin/mount.vboxsf ]
then
    echo "VirtualBox has been detected Please provide your home/user name and hit [Enter]"
    echo "If no name is given, NetBeans will be installed and script will exit Otherwise an attempt will be made
    to mount NetBeansProjects from the host. If this succeeds, an attempt will be made to automatically do this
    during system start up."
    read user
fi
```

Now I try an presumptuous `mount` to the 'myDir'

Is there a way to test this Projects directory after based on the contents? IOW, the directory is not empty and I need to establish that the contents are there because I mounted to the directory and not because the directory already contained them.

Thank you, Yucca

Comment: If you mount a filesystem at some path, the new filesystem will shadow everything that has been at this path before, so all you need to check is if the directory is currently a mount point.  (One way to do the latter might be to call `df myDir` and check if the mount point in the output matches `myDir`.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Hence why I must check if it's contents are there only because of the mount. I can't do a '[-e path]' test as it may not have been empty to start with. The next logic of the script is that due to directory being populated because of the mount, I write the same mount to /etc/rc.local so that user won't have to manually mount each time they want directory populated.

Comment: every directory is there because of a mount - root directory `/` is also mounted. So its every subdirectory on the disk is there because of the mount...

Comment: @Tomas Is there a way though to establish through directory iteration perhaps that just one of the directories is a shared directory from a VirtualBox host system. Does VirtualBox leave any maeans to establish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if `myDir` is a mount point.

```
mountpoint -q myDir && echo "This is a mount point."
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already know it is. I am trying to establish if the directory only contains values because of the mount. It is possible that the directory may have already contained directories and this is what I am trying to establish.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to do. Do you want to check if a certain mount point had files and/or directories inside *after* another filesystem has been mounted on it?

Comment: Sorry I reread your comment thanks + accepted. Gonna try this in an 'if' statement now...

Comment: @thejartender: As I said in my above comment, an previous content of a directory is shadowed if you mount a new filesystem on the path.  Even if there were files in the directory before mounting, you won't see them any more.  Everything you see must be due to the mount.